# Windows 10 authentication against Azure AD

Tags: migration, microsoft-office-365, windows-10, entra-id

I am trying to build a new Windows 10 machine to authenticate against an Azure AD. I have told Windows that the owner of the machine is "My Organisation" and I want to "join Azure AD".

However when I put my username in I get "Your organisation doesn't allow users to set up Windows in this way. Use another email address or set up Windows with a local account".

Is there something I need to configure on the Azure AD? As far as I can tell it should allow all users to authenticate.

I should stress that Azure AD is a trail while I look into the possibility of moving to Office 365.

Comment: Azure AD is not equivalent to Active Directory (on-prem) from a device standpoint.  If you have AD on-prem today, you will likely sync identities to AzureAD/O365, and continue to join workstations to your on-prem domain.  Forgive me if you are already aware of this, I wanted to point out this gap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the configuration settings for the AD domain, you need to make sure that it's configured to allow devices to be joined.  There is more information here - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-conditional-access-device-registration-overview/?rnd=1

Answer (score 1):

There is a step by step guide available here (http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2015/05/28/azure-ad-join-on-windows-10-devices.aspx) that shows how to configure Azure AD to accept Azure AD join on Windows 10 devices.

/!\ carefull : Azure AD join can be use only on Pro, Education & Enterprise editions of Windows 10. No support of this feature on a home version (BYOPC)

hope this help
Regards